# same code is giving different output even when input is same

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

We are given an array and we have to find the element which occured only once in the array.

input:array=1 2 3 6 5 4 4 2 5 3 6 1 6 5 3 2 4 1 2 5 1 4 3 6 8 4 3 1 5 6 2

```
#1
counte=[0]*(max(array)+1)
for i in array:
    counte[i]+=1
for j in range(len(counte)):
    if counte[j]==1:
        print(j)
        break
    else:
        pass


#2
counte=[0 for k in range(max(array)+1)]
for i in array:
    counte[i]+=1
print(counte)
for j in counte:
    if j==1:
        print(counte[j])
        break
    else:
        pass
```

code1 outputs value 8 which is correct but code2 outputs value 5.
I don't understand why code2's output is 5.

Comment: both solutions are pretty inefficient, since you are using O(n) space where you can do it in O(1) space, just look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: ok, I got your point, but then why outputs are different in both the codes.

Comment: because you are doing `counte[j]` when `j=1`, which is `5`, instead you want the index of counte where `j=1` Does that make sense @lokeshbihani

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating it, this should give you count - decide what to do with one that happen only once yourself :)

```
arr = [1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 8, 5, 4, 4]
for i in arr:
    print(str(i) + ' = ' + str(arr.count(i)))
```

PS. if your version is 3.6+ you can make it even nicer with f-strings:

```
    print(f'{i} = {arr.count(i)}')
```